# DL-524 router connected but with not internet connectivity

Tags: internet-connection

My DL-524 router is a bit far away from my laptop, so I bought 20 metres of screened UTP cable.

I've tested the cable and it's okay.

When I plug it in the modem and the router I get no internet connectivity with the WAN LED blinking.

Can someone help?

Comment: Have you tried connecting the two devices using a different (shorter) ethernet cable, without changing anything else in the setup?

Comment: Have you tested internet connectivity from the router itself to confirm it's okay?  Most routers have a built-in traceroute or ping function.

Comment: the two devices are conected with a 0.5m cable and it works fine, but the router is too far.

Comment: Also i've connected the long cable to the modem and dirrectly to an laptop and i have internet.

Answer (score 0):

Verify all TCP/IP settings are correct, verify the laptop is showing up in the arp table/dhcp lease table (depending on type of router and configuration), can you ping the router from laptop? can you ping the DNS servers from your laptop?

Comment: settings should be ok. with the router in the old place internet works ok. with the router in the new position i have no internet connectivity. no settings modified.

Comment: no internet connectivity really doesn't describe much, you need to give specific symptoms. What can you ping as I asked above? Do you get link at all when you plug into the router? What ports are the modem and the computer plugged into? have you tried a different port for the computer?

Answer (score 0):

I know this sounds crazy but it worked for me:

After spending hours looking through posts, resetting the router and going through different configurations time and time again - I found I had mistakenly placed my Internet's Ethernet cable in the LAN slot of the router, not the WAN slot as it should be.

Try putting your Internet cable into one of the LAN connections (1-4) INSTEAD OF the usual place for it (WAN in). It worked for me!